# ajax in ci not updating unkown error in ci

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**This is my controller**

```
public function listCurenrTask()
{   
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->load->model('User_model');
$data['project'] = $this->User_model->select($id);
$this->load->view('taskView',$data );
if ($this->input->post() && $this->input->is_ajax_request()) {                                      $projectid= $this->input->post('$this->session->userdata("projectid")');
$taskstatus = $this->input->post('taskstatus');
$date = $this->input->post('date');
print_r($taskstatus);die();
$credentials = array('projectid'=> $projectid, 'taskstatus'=>$taskstatus, 'date'=>$date);

$this->load->model('User_model');
if(!$this->User_model->taskNotes($credentials)){
    $data['result'] = "fail";
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    $data['result'] = "Success";
    echo json_encode($data);
    redirect('/dashboard');
}
} else {
        // $this->load->view('taskview');
    // }
}
}
```

** have searched a lot of tutorials with POST methods and saw answered questions here too but my POST still doesn't work...I thought i should post it here if you guys see something that i don't!**

**script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        taskstatus=$('#taskstatus').val();
        date=$('#date').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>taskView"
            data : {taskstatus:taskstatus,date:date},
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(response){if(response.result==="fail"){
                        $('.show-message').html("Sorry, failed to change your password");
                    }else{
                        $('.show-message').html("Successfully changes your password");
                    }
            },
            error: function() { 
                            alert("Something went wrong");
            }           
        });
    });``
});
```

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJHVQ.png
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: hai actualy m new to ajax thats why i sufferd a lot in asking the doubts

Answer (score 0):

Did you define your JS variabels?